# SDK Verision dont match

Tags: iphone, debugging, sdk, device

hi my IPhone device has 4.2.1 version, my xcode is saying 4.2 version. Is this any issue because i cant debug my app on device. also the developer folder has iphoneentitlements401 folder, shouldnt it be 4.2 instead of 401?

i am getting cannot read entitlements data ERROR. please help!

Answer (score 0):

### SDK Support:

You need to set your **`IOS Deployment Target`** to the lowest SDK you want to support. So you would need to set yours to at least 4.2.

*Go to* **Project** -> **Edit Project Settings** -> *Scroll down to* **Deployment**, *then find* **IOS Deployment Target**

---

### For Entitlements:

Your entitlements file, if it exists, may be corrupt, remove it if you have it, then add a new one:

Right-click on your Project, then click **Add**, then **New File** and under **iOS** click on **Code Signing** and choose **Entitlements**.

Comment: still same error. i still think iphoneentitlements401 is the creep! god help me!

Comment: can you you update your question with a screen shot of that message? I am not sure where you are getting that error.